# How to understand the QED, QCD and standard model Lagrangians?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics

How do you read the QED, QCD and standard model Lagrangians? What do all the symbols and tensors represent? And, how can you derive them by yourselves?

Comment: QFT textbook will explain the meaning of the symbols and tensors. It is not really a derivation to find these Lagragnians. It is postulated by educated guess and experimental evidence (e.g. parity non-conservation)

Comment: @DIMension10 I would like to regard writing the interaction terms by gauge invariance as an educated guess

Comment: There is an answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/5191